# Need to load XML file to a oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a xml file that I need to load to a table.

Below is the xml file content. How can I load this to the table. Please let me know the best option"

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns:add><Employee_Code>user</Employee_Code><Group_Name>Group</Group_Name>
<Employee_Name>user</Employee_Name><Emp_Mail_ID>abc@gmail.com</Emp_Mail_ID><ID>1</ID><Date>2023-02-17T11:40:26.145</Date></ns:add></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You can store the XML as a XMLType column or as a string (probably CLOB rather than varchar2 if it could be much larger than your example). Or you could extract all the node values and store in a relational table with multiple columns (and/or multiple tables). It depends what you need to do with it afterwards. If you have an existing table then please edit your question to include it's structure, and how you expect the data to appear in that table after it's been loaded from the XML.

Comment: @AlexPoole Right now i dont have a table But i need to have the columns as Employee_code,Group_name, Employee_name , Emp_mail_id,id, date

Comment: OK, where is the file - is it on your client machine (e.g. your PC) where you're running SQL\*Plus, or available to the server via a directory object, or are you going to paste the text into your script?

Comment: File is in a folder on the server say E:\XML_DIR. SQL plus is available in the server and file name Test.xml

Comment: @AlexPoole Is it possible for SQL plus to pick the xml file from server E drive ? When db is actually in another server.

Comment: If it's on the database server and the database has a directory object defined for that path then yes, as a bfile, as Gnqz showed, and can use XMLTable directly against that. Otherwise look at `sqlldr` to create a staging table.

Comment: oh..i don't have access to Db server. I have file at the local and have sql developer /SQL plus through which i can connect .

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, you could [use sqlldr](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb25loa.htm#ADXDB5730) or

`XMLType` constructor to read as `BFILE`, something among the lines:

```
INSERT INTO <your_table>(<stuff>, <'xml destinationcolumn'>)
SELECT <stuff>
     , XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('<xml folder>', 'your_file.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('<charset of the file>'))
  FROM dual;
```